# Migration web application on same farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-application, content-migration

I have this issue when i migrated web application to another on the same farm

"

> Mount-SPContentDatabase : The attach operation cannot continue because
>   another
>
> object in this farm already contains the same ID. Each object in a
>   farm must
>
> have a unique ID. In order to proceed with the attach operation you
>   must
>
> assign a new ID to this database. To attach this database with a new
>   ID, use
>
> the Mount-SPContentDatabase command with the -AssignNewDatabaseId
>   parameter.
>
> Note that if this new database and an existing database contain the
>   same site
>
> collections, attaching this database will likely result in orphaned
>   site
>
> collections due to conflicts between the two databases.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Mount-SPContentDatabase
>
> WSS_Content_PWAProduction_59add0f0f7a54122830179d5a7c2cf ...
>
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ~~~
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ContentDatabase:
> ```
>
> SPCmdletMountContentDatabase) [Mount-SPContentDatabase],
>   SPException
>
> ```
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMountCon
> ```
>
> tentDatabase "

when i use -assighnednewdatabaseid , i had 0 site collection and the site collection didn't migrate

is there any solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

this is expected behavior. You cannot restore/make a copy, a same content DB in the same farm. database ID and site Collection ID stores in the Config db.

In this situation, i would recommend this( i did this just 3 days ago).

- take the backup of Site collection( not the content DB)
- create a new content DB in the 2nd web application.
- Now restore the Site collection in that web application.